# Does Wii U tablet work with wii games?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, wii-u

If I were to play a Wii game on the Wii U, could I play it on the tablet? Using the tablet as the display and use the normal Wii controller+nunchuck to play the game? Or does that not work for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the answer for this question is Yes (with additional conditions though). Latest system update (September 30, 2013) allows all Wii games to be played on Wii U GamePad controller, however original Wii Remote controller is required for games control. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-TV_Play).